# Excel, search multiple columns for cells that contain partial similar data

Tags: excel

Wonder if someone could give me a pointer, or maybe it's already been ask then just a reference, but how can I highlight cells in an excel spreadsheet that contains multiple columns where any portion of a text matches?

Example say cell A2 has the text 'Ionized Sea Salt' and cell D5 has 'Salt'. I would like to highlight those cells because of the matching word 'Salt'.

I don't want to have to add the word I'm searching for in the formula because all the cells and columns will contain hundreds of different strings and I'm looking for matching word(s) per cell.

Thanks

Comment: Are the input terms in a particular range? Or in an Excel Table (aka a ListObject)? How many rows and columns of data is there likely to be? How many cells in total? Should it match on simple words like "of"? You need to give a better description of your problem, and preferably link to a picture or include a bigger amount of sample data

Comment: "Are the input terms in a particular range? Or in an Excel Table (aka a ListObject)? " Sequential range, no skipped cells. Don't answer your second question. "How many rows and columns of data is there likely to be?" Unknown at this time, as present 5 columns with 30 rows will grow in future. "Should it match on simple words like "of"? " No but those words will never be entered."You need to give a better description of your problem, and preferably link to a picture or include a bigger amount of sample data" example would be take all the ingredients from any store bought item.

Answer (score 1):

Untested but should work:

```
Private Sub reset_highlighting()
   ActiveSheet.Cells.Interior.Color = xlNone
End Sub

Private Sub highlight_d5()
    ' Call reset_highlighting < remove comment if you dont want to store prev results
    Dim lr as Long
    lr = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Dim search_range as Range: Set search_range = Range(Cells(1,1), Cells(lr, 1))
    Dim search_value = Range("D5").Value2

    For each cell in search_range
        If (InStr(Trim(LCase(cell.Value2)), Trim(LCase(search_value))) != 0) Then
           cell.Interior.Color = vbYellow
        End If
    Next cell
End Sub
```

> Note, you should replace `ActiveSheet` with `Sheets("YourSheetName")`
>   and also might want to adjust your range to fir the criteria
>   accordingly

---

PS: Post your efforts of you trying to solve the question in the future. Questions where no attempt was made generally tend to get downvoted here, I only made an exception given you're new here *(and I have a good mood today)*

Comment: Well done @Rawrplus, but...shouldn't this be relative slow on a larger database looping through each cell?

Comment: @JvDv yes it absolutely would. Though I feel like it still should be reasonably fast up to 10k cells. In general, you could just pass it to an array to improve the processing speed, but it seems it will not be necessary here **EDIT:** Actually well, pretty much your answer expands on my comment here, so have an upvote :)

Comment: LOL. Exactly what I tried :S Edit: @Rawrplus, you should include clearing of interor color....

Comment: @JvdV I added basic functionality to it, but I don't feel like expanding too much on it because a) user hasn't put much effort into question and b) it wasnt specified by the user himself. Not going to create busywork for myself when I don't have to :)

Comment: I understand...same here, but I also can't stop myself from helping people out. Excel/VBA is enjoyable in these ways :)

Comment: I wasn't really looking for some code I thought it could be don through excel's own conditional formatting or something, e.g. IF, COUNTIF and etc. But I really appreciate the example I'll give it a shot.

Answer (score 1):

Allthough you should have attempted to at least start coding something, this one is quite fun to work on so hereby my attempt :)

```
Sub Hightlight()

Dim MyArray() As String
Dim X As Long
Dim C As Range

ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Cells.Interior.Pattern = xlNone 'Clear the hightlighted cells
MyArray() = Split(ActiveCell.Value, " ") 'Get the activecell and split it in array
For X = LBound(MyArray) To UBound(MyArray) 'Loop through your array using .findnext
    With ActiveSheet.UsedRange
        Set C = .Find(MyArray(X), lookat:=xlPart)
        If Not C Is Nothing Then
            firstaddress = C.Address
            Do
                C.Interior.ColorIndex = 37 'color found matched cells
                Set C = .FindNext(C)
            If C Is Nothing Then
                GoTo DoneFinding
            End If
            Loop While C.Address <> firstaddress
        End If
DoneFinding:
    End With
Next X

End Sub
```

The biggest plus of this approach is it wont have to go through thousands of cells, so therefor should be relative fast.

I am sure some true expert can cleanup this code even better :)

**Input:**

[image]

**Output:**

[image]

So.... add a button to your sheet, assign the macro, select a cell, hit the button...